# loosing values when I write to csv using to_csv with separator

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Not sure why i am loosing some values when I use separator(any) to save dataframe to csv.
Thanks a lot for your help
The input dataframe is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuFrN.png)
So when I use
df.to_csv(csv_file, index=False, date_format='%m-%d-%Y', sep='-')
output is (note I have removed the delimiter'-' in the csv bellow screenshot manually to make the screenshot look clear). Main point is I am missing some values from some rows randomly like 1M Libor from 4th and 6th row with delimiter on. With out delimiter it saves the csv as it is in dataframe

[image]

```
                 VS
```

df.to_csv(csv_file, index=False, date_format='%m-%d-%Y')
output is

[image]

Comment: can you include a screenshot of the raw file, i.e. the input prior to running code?

Comment: added to the original question